# Sending C++ class object through the NSNotificationCenter in Box2d. Error: No viable conversion from 'MyContact' to 'id'

Tags: c++, objective-c, listener, contacts, nsnotificationcenter

I try to implement **Contact Listener** in **box2d** **cocos2d**. And I want integrate  **NSNotificationCenter** in **PostSolve** function, but when I try to point the **object:** parametr I've got the error:

```
No viable conversion from 'MyContact' to 'id'
```

How can I send MyContact object through the NSNotificationCenter?

MyContactListener class

```
 //
    //  MyContactListener.m
    //  Box2DPong
    //
    //  Created by Ray Wenderlich on 2/18/10.
    //  Copyright 2010 Ray Wenderlich. All rights reserved.
    //

    #import "MyContactListener.h"
    #import "ConfigMacro.h"

    MyContactListener::MyContactListener() : _contacts(),_contactsObjects(){}

    MyContactListener::~MyContactListener() {}

    void MyContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact) {

        b2Body *bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

        if(bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL)
        {
            MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
            _contacts.push_back(myContact);
        }
    }

    void MyContactListener::EndContact(b2Contact* contact) {

        MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB() };
        std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
        pos = std::find(_contacts.begin(), _contacts.end(), myContact);
        if (pos != _contacts.end()) {
            _contacts.erase(pos);
        }
    }
   void MyContactListener::PreSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2Manifold* oldManifold) {}

    void MyContactListener::PostSolve(b2Contact* contact, const b2ContactImpulse* impulse) {

        b2Body *bodyA = contact->GetFixtureA()->GetBody();
        b2Body *bodyB = contact->GetFixtureB()->GetBody();

        if(bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL)
        {
        int32 count = contact->GetManifold()->pointCount;
        float32 maxImpulse = 0.0f;
        b2Vec2 collision;

        for (int32 i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
            maxImpulse = b2Max(maxImpulse, impulse->normalImpulses[i]);
            if (i == 0) {
                b2WorldManifold worldManifold;
                contact->GetWorldManifold(&worldManifold);
                collision = worldManifold.points[0];
            }
        }
        MyContact myContact = { contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB(), maxImpulse, collision };

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kReceivedImpulse object:myContact userInfo:nil];

        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object:` argument should be a pointer to an Objective-C object - you're trying to pass what looks like a struct.

Comment: Ok, I have made the MyContactObjectClass class and now I can send this class object though the NSNotificationCenter. 

But now after then I received the message from Notification and I try to create the b2Body and I've got another one error after: 

Assertion failed: (IsLocked() == false), function CreateBody, file

Can the NSNotificationCenter lock the b2World?

Comment: @AlexanderSharunov: It has no idea what a `b2World` is, so no, it can't. Post a new question with your body creation code to see if someone might help.

Comment: Maybe You can help me with question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515411/calculation-the-square-of-intersection-two-box2d-b2polygon